# Chef - Run resource on other resource's failure

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have two `execute` resources called `command_1` and `command_2`.

If `command_1` fails, I want to run `command_2`and then re-run `command_1`.

Pretty much like this:

```
execute 'command_1' do
  command "ipa host-del #{machine_name}"
  action :run
  ignore_failure true
  on_failure { notifies :run, 'execute['command_2']', :immediately }
end

execute 'command_2' do
  command "ipa host-mod --certificate  #{machine_name}"
  action :nothing
  notifies :run, 'execute['command_1']', :immediately
end
```

How can I replace `on_failure` (would be great if Chef had this one) by something that actually works ?

Comment: I see no direct way. Can you instead guard the second resource with a `not_if`/`only_if` block that prevents it from running, when the first resource was successful? I.e. when the `host-del` failed, I expect something similar `ipa host-list #{machine_name}` to include the host. Check for this in a `not_if { mixlib shellout blabla contains #{machine_name}`.

Comment: I assume command_1 has a guard to not be executed at each chef run, so I think your best bet is using directly [shell_out](https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#shell-out) within a ruby_block and implementing the logic in this block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to put command_2 first and then guard it by checking if it needs to be run or not.  I'm not sure what that command does, but if it is possible to verify somehow if it is needed or not, then you could do things this way.

If there is no way to verify whether or not command_2 is needed, then you could do something like this instead:

```
execute 'command_1' do
  command "ipa host-del #{machine_name} && touch /tmp/successful"
  action :run
  ignore_failure true
end

execute 'command_2' do
  command "ipa host-mod --certificate  #{machine_name}"
  action :run
  notifies :run, 'execute['command_1']', :immediately
  not_if { ::File.exist? '/tmp/successful' }
end

file '/tmp/successful' do
  action :delete
end
```

This will run command_1 and if it is successful it will `touch /tmp/successful`.  command_2 will then run, but only if `/tmp/successful` does not exist.  IF command_2 does run, it will then notify command_1 to run again immediately.  To clean up for the next run, we then add the `file` resource to ensure `/tmp/successful` is removed

Comment: Nice. The code doesn't show up as a code block, could you fix that ?

Comment: no problem @JahMyst.  Not sure what happened there as I did have the formatting correct before.  O-well.

Comment: After reading a bit more on this, I want to add that a better practice would be to use ```creates '/tmp/successful'``` inside the ```execute``` resource to create the temporary file.
```creates``` is an attribute of the ```execute``` resource, as shown here: https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html

Comment: @OlivierCervello `creates` does not actually create a file.  It's just a shortcut for `not_if { ::File.exist?(<file path>) }`  You could use it on `execute 'command_2'` but your intent would be less clear as `command_2` is not in any way expected to create that file.

Comment: You're right I got it all wrong. It's a bit misleading though.